# WordPress menu page is showing from the URL after hide it

Tags: wordpress

I am hiding the menu from the user account using bellow code;

```
function hide_menu_from_user () {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' ); 
        remove_menu_page( 'vc-welcome' ); 
    }   
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'hide_menu_from_user', 999 );
```

Now, those menu is not showing but if you use the URL and paste it then the page is coming for example:

If I use this URL I can see the Contact Form Plugin but I hide it from the user account dashboard menu, right?

www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7

How can I solve it? Is there anything wrong in above code?

Comment: Have you tried logging in as user?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code:-

```
function hide_menu_from_user () {
    if ( !current_user_can( "administrator") ) {
      remove_admin_url_access( "edit-comments.php" );
      remove_admin_url_access( "wpcf7" );
      remove_admin_url_access( "tools.php" );
      remove_admin_url_access( "vc-welcome" );
    }   
}
add_action( "admin_menu", "hide_menu_from_user", 999 );

if(!function_exists('remove_admin_url_access') ) {
    function remove_admin_url_access($menu_to_hide){
        global $pagenow;
        global $parent_file;

        remove_menu_page( $menu_to_hide );

        if($menu_to_hide == $pagenow || $menu_to_hide == $parent_file  ) {
            do_action( "admin_page_access_denied" );
           wp_die( __( "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." ), 403 );
        }
    }
}
```